# Using an absolute path after XPath following-sibling

Tags: html, xpath

I am using the following XPath search:

```
getNodeSet(doc, "//img[@src = './images/min_es.gif']/../../following-sibling::tr")
```

The result is a `<tr>` that contains two table (one within the other) so:

```
<tr valign="top"><td height="163">&#13;
    <table width="128" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="163"><tr valign="top"><td width="96">&#13;
          <table width="126"><tr><td width="65%" valign="top"><font size="1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&#13;
                                   Microclina</font></td>&#13;
                                 <td width="35%" valign="top"><font size="1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&#13;
                                   ~40 %</font></td>&#13;
                               </tr><tr><td width="65%" valign="top"><font size="1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&#13;
                                   Quartzo</font></td>&#13;
                                 <td width="35%" valign="top"><font size="1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&#13;
                                   ~29 %</font></td>&#13;
                               </tr><tr><td width="65%" valign="top"><font size="1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&#13;
                                   Plagioclase</font></td>&#13;
                                 <td width="35%" valign="top"><font size="1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&#13;
                                   ~20 %</font></td>&#13;
                               </tr><tr><td width="65%" valign="top"><font size="1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&#13;
                                   Biotite</font></td>&#13;
                                 <td width="35%" valign="top"><font size="1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&#13;
                                   ~10 %</font></td>&#13;
                               </tr></table></td>&#13;
      </tr></table></td>&#13;
</tr>
```

Now I would like to access the inner table. To do this I have tried:

```
getNodeSet(doc, "//img[@src = './images/min_es.gif']/../../following-sibling::tr//table")
```

which give me a list of all of the tables (in this case the two tables above, one of which has both tables).

I have also tried:

```
 getNodeSet(doc, "//img[@src = './images/min_es.gif']/../../following-sibling::tr//table/table")
```

which gets me nothing. I have tried many variation among them this one:

```
getNodeSet(doc, "//img[@src = './images/min_es.gif']/../../following-sibling::tr[1]/.//table/table")
```

but I cannot get to that elusive inner table.

Can anyone show me how? Any references appreciated.

Comment: I have solved this. Seems I don't quite understand XPath yet. Solution is `getNodeSet(doc, "//img[@src = './images/min_es.gif']/../../following-sibling::tr//table//table")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are throwing in `//` haphazardly when you don't seem to understand what it does.

```
path//table
```

Means "select all `tables` anywhere beneath `path`. That's why it was selecting all the tables when you tried it. What you should be using is either:

```
//img[@src = './images/min_es.gif']/../../following-sibling::tr/table/tr/td/table
```

or

```
//img[@src = './images/min_es.gif']/../../following-sibling::tr/table//table
```

The first one means:

```
//img[@src = './images/min_es.gif']/../../following-sibling::tr
```

Select the `tr`

```
/table
```

Select any `table`s that are children of that `tr`.

```
/tr
```

Select any `tr`s that are children of those `table`s.

```
/td
```

Select any `td` that are children of those `tr`s.

```
/table
```

Select any `table`s that are children of those `td`s.

In the second example, we have:

```
/table
```

Select any `table`s are children of the selected the `tr`(s).

```
//table
```

Select any tables that are anywhere below that `table`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Believe it or not I had tried your first suggestion but failed. I went back to see why it failed. Unfortunately I had not seen that after the `<tr>` there was still another `<td>` before the first `<table>`. Once again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this. Seems like I don't quite understand XPath yet. Solution is

```
`getNodeSet(doc, "//img[@src = './images/min_es.gif']/../../following-sibling::tr//table//table")`
```

Whenever a query returns one or more elements, you have to use "//" to match on the answer set.

Comment: "*Whenever a query returns one or more elements, you have to use "//" to match on the answer set.*"  **No.**  Use `//` to select descendant (or self) nodes and `/` to select immediate child nodes.  For example, `//para` will select all paragraphs in a document; `.//para` will select all paragraphs at or beneath the current context node.